# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function delete(), 4 and exactly 5 expected but i have 5 argument

Tags: php, sql

I can't understand my mistake ' Too few arguments to function delete(), 4 and exactly 5 expected  but i have 5 argument ! I can't find a solution

```php
// Permet delete un article

    function delete($title, $content, $posted, $post_id, $id)
    {

        // connexion a la bd
        global $db;
    
        // tableau pour la requête
        $e = [
            'id'        => $id,
            'id'        => $post_id
        ];
    
        $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=:id";
        $datas = array(':id' => $id);
    
        try {
            $req = $db->prepare($sql);
            $res = $req->execute($datas);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo " Erreur : " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE post_id=:id";
        $datas = array(':id' => $id);
    
        try {
            $req = $db->prepare($sql);
            $res = $req->execute($datas);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo " Erreur : " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return !empty($res) ? $res : false;     
        return !empty($res) ? $res : false;
 }
```

I think the problem is with second delete(delete from comments) because the first request works but not the second.

Here is the function called

```php
if(isset($_POST['supri'])) {
        $title = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['title']));
        $content = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['content']));

        $post_id = htmlspecialchars(trim($_COMMENTS['post_id']));

        $posted = isset($_POST['public']) ? "1" : "0";
        $errors = [];
        delete($title,$content,$posted,$post_id,$id);
```

Comment: The error says that you are calling your `delete` function with 4 arguments instead of 5. You have shown the implementation of `delete` (where it has 5) but you didn't show where you _call_ `delete` (which is where the bug will be, unless it's library code that expects your function to have 4 arguments and not 5 - in this case the bug is your function signature). Please show where `delete` is called.

Comment: The problem will not come from my function ? But from my button that calls the function

Comment: `delete($title,$content,$posted,$_GET['id']);` that's 4 parameters. You are missing either the `post_id` or the `id`.

Comment: I just added 'post_id' there is no more error ! Thank you The problem now is that when I delete a post nothing works But now I have a good pist to find the solution !

Comment: the problem now is that there is no more error and my request does not work! how to find a solution if there is no problem it becomes complicated!

Comment: [Approach it systematically](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I found ! the problem came from my requests I had to separate them into two requests except that the request to stop after the first request I just had to combine the two requests! Thanks everyone for your comments and help!